# Installing PHP, MySql and Apache on windows

Tags: php, windows, apache

Its my first time working with Apache,PHP,MySql. I downloaded and installed the latest package of these 3. Now I checked with apache and the index.html works. Now I replaced the index.html with some php script to check if my php works or not. When opened the html page again I see the php code directly. It seems it does not work. following is how my php code looks like.

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

when I open my index.php , I see the above code itself. Can anybody let me know whats wrong and how can i fix it?

Comment: Either your PHP isn't correctly installed or the type `.php` hasn't been added to your Apache configuration (`httpd.conf`) yet.

Comment: Are you visiting the page through `localhost/index.php` or through your regular file system path to the file? Make sure you are using localhost.

Comment: Try using wamp, it will be much easier to get set up and running.

Comment: I suggest that instead of fixing what appears to be one issue, but is likely many issues with your apache installation (I have had alot of issues when I did it, trying to get php to talk to mysql and apache etc). I found this was so easy, i defineately recommend it. Install all 3 at once via one installer! See here for the download: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/

WAMP is the windows version. If you would like a linux version you could try LAMP.

Comment: Please note that you never install WAMP on your production machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your apache httpd.conf file for some commented out code that looks like this

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

and further down the file, this...

```
<IfModule php5_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    <IfModule dir_module>
            DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't find the libphp5.so file neither in my Apache or PHP installation locations. How to do it? Mine is httpd-2.2.21 apache and php 5.3.8. Please suggest.

Comment: ah, I'm not on windows now, but wherever Apache installed to, look under conf/ and you should find this httpd.conf file.  Either add or uncomment the lines I listed above

Comment: I found the httpd.conf file. But where can i find the libphp5.so file? so that I can set the path. Even in httpd.conf file also I dint find it commented.

Comment: How about a file that looks like this: c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll

Comment: I'm done for the night, if this didn't do the trick, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873734/php-extensions-wont-load-on-apache-startup - It looks similar to your situation

Answer (score 1):

it seems there is some problem in the installation. use WAMP as stefan and dessus or XAMPP. i recomand u to use XAMPP its bundled with APACHE, MYSQL, File Zilla Server, Mercury for mail. Easy to Install and Use . http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Answer (score 1):

Another vote for WampServer. Once you have a working server, it's then easier to poke around with configurations files and then learn Apache/PHP configuration that way.

Answer (score 0):

use wamp! it's easy and fast :)

http://www.wampserver.com/en/

personally, i use an old version from 2007, 1.7.4, it can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files%2FWAMP5/

the good thing about using an old version is that your code will work on old machines, and many servers out there have old versions of php and mysql.

the bad thing about using an old version is that your code might not work on new machines, and some machines out there have new versions of php and mysql.

Answer (score -1):

http://computing-know.blogspot.in/#!/2013/10/how-to-setup-apache-php-mysql.html

Step By Step Process to Setup Apaache,PHP,Mysql,phpMyAdmin and XDebug.

1)How to install Apache

2)Setup PHP for Apache

3)Install & Configure MySQL to use with PHP

4)Setup XDebug for Debugging

5)phpMyAdmin

Note:In this tutorial my Server Folder is located on F:\Server

How to install Apache

1)There are two ways to install apache either install the old version of apache httpd (Compatible with Windows XP) from httpd.apache.org/download.cgi or get the latest apache build zip from www.apachelounge.com/download/ .

2)I will show how to configure apache from the zip version downloaded from apachelounge.com/download/ .

3)Click on Additional + VC9 on the left of the page.

4)Download the 2.4.x zip build with OpenSSL 0.9.8.

5)Create a folder with a name Server on location where .

6)My Location is F:\Server

7)Extract the Apache24 from apache zip to the Server folder.

8)Now Goto config folder in Apache and open httpd.config in any text editor.

9)Find(Ctrl + F) and replace each and every instance of "c:/Apache24" and change it to your apache location in my case its f:/Server/Apaache24.

ServerRoot "c:/Apache24" with ServerRoot "f:/Server/Apache24"

DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs" with DocumentRoot "f:/Server/Apache24/htdocs"

with

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin/" with ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "f:/Server/Apache24/cgi-bin/"

with

8)Now run the Command Prompt (with Administrator Rights) .

9)On Command Prompt go to the location Server/Apache24/bin .

10)Inside the Bin folder type "httpd -k install" to install the Apache service and then press Enter.

11)To start the Apache Server simply type in "httpd -k start" and then press Enter.

12)Restart Your Computer

13)Now Open the Bin folder and double click on the ApacheMonitor.exe and Start Apache

14)Now Goto localhost if you see page "It Works" then Apache is sucessfully installed on you computer.

If you see a page that says "It works!" then the Apache server has been installed successfully.

Setup PHP for Apache

1)Goto windows.php.net/download/ download the php-5.4.x-Win32-VC9-x86.zip.

2)Create a folder named php inside Server folder.

3)Extract all files from php-5.4.x-Win32-VC9-x86.zip to php folder in the Server.

4)Now Goto config folder in Apache and open httpd.config in any text editor.

5)Find(Ctrl + F) the LoadModule scroll down until last LoadModule and Paste the following

LoadModule php5_module "f:/Server/php/php5apache2_4.dll".

6) Find(Ctrl + F) the AddType scroll down until last AddType and Paste the following

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .

7)Add the PHP location to the end of the httpd.conf file. For example, at the end of the file, add the following: PHPIniDir "Your PHP Location".

localhost/info.php

8)In the php folder rename the php.ini-development to php.ini and open it in Text Editor.

9)Find(Ctrl + F) the display_errors, and make sure the value is set to On.

10) Find(Ctrl + F) the extension_dir = "./" and change it to extension_dir = "F:\Server\php\ext" .

11)Restart Apache Server.

12)Create a file "phpinfo.php" in htdocs folder in Apache with follwoing content:

13)Goto localhost/phpinfo.php

extension_dir = "./"

14)Right Click MyComputer Click Propertes

15)Click Environment Variables

16)Add Your php folder location at the end of the path

17)Restart Your Computer.

Install & Configure MySQL to use with PHP

1)Goto dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ download the zip or installer version.

2)Install MySQL

3)Click Next

4)Select Complete & click Next

5)Click Finsh

6)Click Standard Configuration

7)Click Next

8)Enter the password for mySQL

9)Goto MySQL Command Line and enter the password.

12)Open the php.ini file and find the line: ;extension=php_mysql.dll remove the semi-colon.

and find the line: ;extension=php_mysql.dll

phpMyAdmin

1)Goto config folder in Apache and open httpd.config in any text editor.

2) Find(Ctrl + F) the line DirectoryIndex index.html add index.php.

3)Open php.ini file in the Server Folder and Uncomment the mbstring and mysqli extension.

3)Goto phpmyadmin.net/ Download the latest phpMyAdmin-4.0.8-english.zip.

4)Extract it to phpMyAdmin folder in htdocs.

5)Restart the Apache Server.

6)Goto localhost/phpMyAdmin/

Setup XDebug for Debugging

1)Goto http://xdebug.org/download.php from your browser and download the

php_xdebug-2.x.x-5.4-vc9 Thread Safe 32 bit version.

2)Copy and Paste it to the extension folder in the php.

3)Copy & Paste the following line of code at the end of php.ini file .

[XDebug]

;; Only Zend OR (!) XDebug

zend_extension="Your Location of Xdebug"

xdebug.remote_enable=true

xdebug.remote_host=localhost

xdebug.remote_port=10000

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp

4)Restart Apache Server.

5)Goto to localhost/phpinfo.php scroll down to see if xDebug is installed