# Getting a short serverside php script to work on apache

Tags: php, apache

I  just installed apache and php on a windows 7 installation.

in the apache htdocs directory I put a file called "testing.php"

in it I wrote

```
<?php
echo "Maple|Pine|Oak|Ash";
?>
```

when I visit the page though it just spits out everything (rather than actually echoing the words) .

this is my first time running a web server or anything so I was wondering what I am doing wrong?

Comment: your apache server is not configured to handle php scripts. Check [`installing-php-mysql-and-apache-on-windows`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736973/installing-php-mysql-and-apache-on-windows)

Comment: what is the Url you used to visit the page? htt://localhost/...?

Answer (score -1):

**You need to install PHP also.** Apache does not come with PHP in it, it has to be installed and properly enabled. Consider [**WAPM**](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) *(to learn .htaccess too, for Linux hosting)* or [**IIS Express** + **Web Platform Installer**](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview) *(+ PHP + PHP Win Cache + URL Rewrite - these are found in WebPI and are easy to install)*.

Comment: The first line reads `apache and php`, so PHP seems to be installed.

Comment: @Nanne Doesn't look like it iNanne. If it spits out the raw code, handlers are not setup right. So... it's not really installed. Next time read and read more and understand what you're reading... as he explains that it's not properly installed (as he gets source code dumped in browser).

Comment: Your answer reads "you need to install PHP also", not "it is not setup right". That is really something different, and saying "apache does not come with php in it" is not really adding anything if @notig allready seems to understand that by saying php was installed?  If you mean to say "php is not installed correctly" say that (in a comment if you can't help any more then that).

Comment: @Nanne I helped! I gave alternatives. WAMP is easy. WAMP is preinstalled. IIS Express is easy. Point and click installation. It don't get more helpful than this. (You don't know when to quit.)

Comment: I installed apache to c:\apache

Comment: @NoTiG Bad idea. C:\* path in Windows will give your permission problems. Consider another partition or \Program Files. Get WAMP and use that. See how it goes.

Comment: When I test configuration under apache it says cannot load the php5apache module (which is in my c:\php  folder . I added these three lines to my httpd.conf  according to a text I am reading:  LoadModule php_module c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "c:\php"